# MatTable - Angular Material: Could not find column with id

Tags: angular, forms, angular-material, mat-table

I'm trying to display a table "programmatically":

```
<div [formArrayName]="doc.typeSelector">
                  {{ doc.typeSelector }}
</div>
<div *ngIf="documents[doc.typeSelector]">
     <mat-table
      [dataSource]="documents[doc.typeSelector]"
      *ngFor="let col of docColumns">
      <ng-container [matColumnDef]="col">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{ col | uppercase }} </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{ element[col] }} </td>
      </ng-container>
    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="docColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: docColumns;"></tr>
  </mat-table>
</div>
```

Where:

```
documents: object = {};
docColumns: string[] = ["name", "uploadDate", "uri", "comments"];
docs = [];
docForm: FormGroup;
docTypes: object = {
    fs: 'Financial Statements',
    id: 'Identity Document',
    ad: 'Bank Account Details',
    cd: 'Constitutional Document',
    pd: 'Power Document',
  };
```

and where the `documents / docs / docFrom` variables are being populated with `ngOnInit()` :

```
[...] this.docForm = this.fb.group({});
    Object.keys(this.docTypes).map(
      type => {
        this.docForm.addControl(type, this.fb.array([]));
        this.docs.push({
         typeName: this.docTypes[type],
         typeSelector: type
        });
    }
  );
```

Then if there's a customer, a subscription gets the data from the database...
and once we get the information it gets aggregated in the variables:

```
// Info for the docForm:
              const cusDocs = this.customer.docRefs;
              Object.keys(cusDocs).map(docType => {
                const currDocs = [];
                cusDocs[docType].forEach(doc => {
                  currDocs.push(this.customerService.createNewDoc(doc));
                });
                const matchForm = this.docForm.get(docType) as FormArray;
                currDocs.forEach(form => {
                  matchForm.push(form);
                });
              });
              Object.keys(this.docForm.value).map(docType => {
                const currForm = this.docForm.get(docType) as FormArray;
                if (currForm.value.length > 0) {
                  Object.keys(currForm.value).map(doc => {
                    const currentDoc = currForm.at(+doc).value;
                    const newDocRow = {
                      name: currentDoc.name,
                      uploadDate: currentDoc.uploadDate,
                      uri: currentDoc.uri,
                      comments: currentDoc.comment
                    };
                    if (!this.documents[docType]) {
                      this.documents[docType] = [];
                    }
                    this.documents[docType].push(newDocRow);
                    console.log(this.documents[docType]);
                  });
                }
              });
              console.log(this.documents);
              console.log(this.docColumns);
```

- The `docs array` is used by the DOM to display an expansion-panel
- The `docTypes object` is used to build the previous variable, matching the response from the server. Might be useless but at the time I built this, I wanted to make sure that the server information matched the DOM...
- `docForm` is a `FormGroup` holding the 5 different documents type that can be uploaded.
- `docColumns` are the displayedColumns set in advance.
- Last but not least, `documents` is the `array` of `object` used to define the rows.

Here's what the `console.logs` yield: 
[image: Logs + error]

I've seen similar questions but I'm not sure that my error fits these cases...
Thanks in advance!

EDIT ----------------------
EDIT: Olipej's answer didn't seem to solve my issue or I'm having trouble understand where my error comes from.

I made a stackblitz reproducing my data structure and the error I'm getting:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-table-error-example

Stackblitz screenshots: 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your ngFor loop is set on the mat-table element. You want to use the loop on the ng-container element to fill your table with data.
Now you are generating multiple mat-table's with incorrect data..

Change this and you will see the magic happen :)

Comment: Hey Olipej! Either I didn't get the answer correctly or it doesn't seem to work either. Here's a link to a stackblitz reproducing the error: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eh8jqu

Comment: There is no mat-table in your stackblitz.. Have you linked wrong?

Comment: @Ardzii? I saw you didn't have other projects on stackblitz. Is it a mistake or not?
If not I suggest you create a new angular project locally or stackblitz and create a mat-table with lesser data. That way you can grasp the concept and then apply it to your bigger project.

Comment: The link works fine for me... I've commented the mat-table part to prove that the data is there through a simple <div> with a bunch of <p>s.

Comment: Here, I changed the name... https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-table-error-example let me know if it works better.

Comment: @Ardzii Okey... The problem was that the StackBlitz example did not use any mat-table component.
Read about mat-table here:
https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview

If you need help with something other it's a diffrent question and this issue should be marked as solved and you should open a new issue with your current errors.
Good luck!

Comment: There must be a bug of some sort. I can clearly see my mat-table in the stackblitz when I click the link...Check ou in the main question

Comment: Ahh you comment out the code producing error... What a devious way to present an error example.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that the object(s) you are passing to matTable all have properties matching column ids?

At the start of the template you check for an element in 'documents' but you never check for it's properties.

```
<div *ngIf="documents[doc.typeSelector]">
```

Of course you shouldn't have to check if properties exist but because you get the error: 'Could not find column with id "uploadDate"' I don't think the object you passed actually have the property yet.

If this doesn't help, could you provide a stackblitz example?

Comment: Hey kebbaben! Thanks for your answer. I'm not sure what you mean, though, by: "At the start of the template you check for an element in 'documents' but you never check for it's properties." I've checked the `doc.typeSelector` and these are the correct ones: `{'fs', 'cd', 'id' etc...}`. You think that my problems comes up at the passing of that variables?

Comment: Or it might be that the typeSelector doesn't match the actual selector for the FormArray.

Comment: @Ardzii Sorry I misinterpreted the error. The problem is that mat table doesn't register the column definition. Either the reference is invalid in some way or it doesn't initialise before matTable somehow.

You could try matColumnDef="{{col}}" on ng-container
or *matRowDef="let row; columns: ['name', 'uploadDate', 'uri', 'comments'];" on tr mat-row.

Comment: Hey kebbaben! Thanks for the follow-up! I'll try these solutions and keep you posted. I was reordering and factoring my variables anyways since it was a bit of a mess...

Comment: @Ardzii You should check Ollpej's answer. That will most likely solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks kebbaben for the followup! It indeed seems to be the answer to my question.

Comment: Still not working ... Here's a stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eh8jqu

Comment: @Ardzii the stackblitz you linked doesn't even use mat-table but expansion panels. This doesn't even seem to match the code in the original question. Can you update your stackblitz?

Comment: Let me change the name of the stackblitz.... https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-table-error-example

Comment: @Ardzii changing the name of the url won't change the content of your code... Your question revolves around the use of matTable, but your stackblitz example doesn't use it at all! You need to rethink what you need help with.

Comment: There must be a bug of some sort. I can clearly see my mat-table in the stackblitz when I click the link...Check ou in the main question

Answer (score 0):

I'm creating a new answer as I will need to cover more than comments allow.

First of all you linked a stackblitz example that doesn't match the code in your question. Neither your use of mat-table nor your the data you want to display. Both are structured differently between the code in the question and the code in the example.

I think you first need to ask yourself what it is that you want to accomplish. Then you need to ask yourself what you need to solve the problem you're having.

Now if you still believe that using mat-table is what you need, then I will help you use it with dynamic columns.

To begin with mat-table need an array of objects to display and a definition of column ids.

```
export interface PeriodicElement {
  name: string;
  position: number;
  weight: number;
  symbol: string;
}

const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [
  {position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H'},
  {position: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He'},
  {position: 3, name: 'Lithium', weight: 6.941, symbol: 'Li'},
  {position: 4, name: 'Beryllium', weight: 9.0122, symbol: 'Be'},
  {position: 5, name: 'Boron', weight: 10.811, symbol: 'B'},
  {position: 6, name: 'Carbon', weight: 12.0107, symbol: 'C'},
  {position: 7, name: 'Nitrogen', weight: 14.0067, symbol: 'N'},
  {position: 8, name: 'Oxygen', weight: 15.9994, symbol: 'O'},
  {position: 9, name: 'Fluorine', weight: 18.9984, symbol: 'F'},
  {position: 10, name: 'Neon', weight: 20.1797, symbol: 'Ne'},
];

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];
  dataSource = ELEMENT_DATA;
}
```

`dataSource` uses `ELEMENT_DATA` which is an array of objects.

`displayedColumns` is a string array of ids and is the definition of every column. Note that every string in this array must match any of the property/variable names of `PeriodicElement`, **case sensitive**.

And this is how you use mat-table.

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let col of displayedColumns" [matColumnDef]="col">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{col}} </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element[col]}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

mat-table requires a data source to display anything. Notice where I put the *ngFor? I put it on the ng-container because one ng-container is one column. I loop through `displayedColumns`. The array of ids, and use them to get properties of `element`.

[Here is a working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-table-dynamic-columns)

Although if the property names in the data objects you are using never change. You do not even need to loop the columns dynamically, and I really recommend that you just read the standard documentation of angular mat-table and test the example-code.

I hope this helps you with your problems.